# django: queryset doesnt show the right result

Tags: django

I'm not sure how to write the queryset since I have a list of categories, my try is below, however, I'm not getting the wanted result. Any help is appreciated!

model:

```
    category= (('sell', 'sell'),('rent','rent'))
    categories= models.CharField(max_length = 10, choices= category,  null = True)
```

html:

```
               <select name="type" class="form-control " style = "width:250px;">
                     <option selected="true" disabled="disabled" selected>Type</option>   
                     <option value="sell" class = 'numbers'>sell</option>
                     <option value="rent" class = 'numbers'>rent</option> 
               </select>
```

views>query>

```
# type
if 'types' in request.GET:
    types= request.GET['types']
    if types:
        queryset_list = queryset_list.filter(category__in = ['sell','rent'])
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `name` is *type* in `<selected>`. So, check for *type*, not *types*:

```
if 'type' in request.GET:
    types= request.GET.get('type')
    
    # Check for valid type
    if types in ['sell', 'rent']:
        queryset_list = queryset_list.filter(categories=types)
```